# How to disable an option which is already selected from dropdown list?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In a React project using antd library, I've created a list of options from a json data which is populated as a drop-down list. Following is the code for reference

The json data

```
const newData = [
  {
    id: 123,
    name: "Vijay"
  },
  {
    id: 345,
    name: "Sanket"
  },
  {
    id: 546,
    name: "Hitesh"
  },
  {
    id: 789,
    name: "Sameer"
  },
  {
    id: 421,
    name: "Akshay"
  }
];
```

That data is used over here in `<Select/>`

```
<h2>Data 1</h2>
    <Select
      onChange={(key, val) => handleOnValuesChange(key, val)}
      placeholder="Select any one"
      style={{ width: 120 }}
      options={newData.map((_) => ({
        label: _.name,
        value: _.id
      }))}
      bordered={false}
    />
    <br />
    <h2>Data 2</h2>
    <Select
      onChange={(key, val) => handleOnValuesChange(key, val)}
      placeholder="Select any one"
      style={{ width: 120 }}
      options={newData.map((_) => ({
        label: _.name,
        value: _.id
      }))}
      bordered={false}
    />
```

The onChange function

```
const handleOnValuesChange = (key, val) => {
  const allData = newData.map((data) => {
    if (data.id === val) {
      return {
        ...data,
        disabled: true
      };
    } else {
      return {
        ...data,
        disabled: false
      };
    }
  });
  console.log("NEW DATA", allData);
};
```

When Vijay and Akshay is selected, I'am expecting the data as

```
0: {id: 1, value: "Vijay", disabled: true } 
1: {id: 2, value: "Sanket", disabled: false}
2: {id: 3, value: "Hitesh", disabled: false }
3: {id: 4, value: "Sameer", disabled: false }
4: {id: 5, value: "Akshay", disabled: true }
```

but getting output as

```
0: {id: 1, value: "Vijay", disabled: false } {/* This disabled should change to true */}
1: {id: 2, value: "Sanket", disabled: false}
2: {id: 3, value: "Hitesh", disabled: false }
3: {id: 4, value: "Sameer", disabled: false }
4: {id: 5, value: "Akshay", disabled: true }
```

How to tackle this? Any appropriate solution highly appreciated

This is the codesandbox link as: https://codesandbox.io/s/bordered-less-antd-4-17-0-alpha-7-forked-wtur0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The newData should be stored in a state inorder to achieve disabling of options already selected. This is because the DOM gets re-rendered only if props or state is updated.

So in your code since the data is not stored in any state it does not change the non focused option, once the focused option is changed.

I have made some changes to the code and added the working example in [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/bordered-less-antd-4-17-0-alpha-7-forked-5kg4v).

```
  const [data, setData] = React.useState(updatedData); //store the newData with disabled added
  const [prevKey, setPrevKey] = React.useState(null); //store the last changed option



  const handleOnValuesChange = (key, val) => {
    const updating = [...data];
    setPrevKey(val.value);
    data.map((d, i) => {
      if (d.id === val.value) {
        updating[i] = {
          ...d,
          disabled: true
        };
      }
      if (d.id === prevKey) { //this toggles the previous selected value to false
        updating[i] = {
          ...d,
          disabled: false
        };
      }
    });
    setData(updating);
  };



.....
<Select
        onChange={(key, val) => handleOnValuesChange(key, val)}
        placeholder="Select any one"
        style={{ width: 120 }}
        options={data
          .filter((d) => d.disabled === false) //this shows only the options that are not disabled
          .map((_) => {
          console.log(_.name)
          console.log(_.id)
          return({
            label: _.name,
            value: _.id
          })})}
```

Comment: Very nice logic and useful code, but, two things were observed. 1) When selecting any option its respective 'id' is displayed and 2) When one option is selected it should have disabled or filtered out in second i.e if I select  'Hitesh' in the first dropdown and select 'Sanket' in the second dropdown, 'Sanket' should be filtered out in first and 'Hitesh' in the second.

Comment: 'id' being shown is mostly probably because of an issue with antd select. I have made edit in the sandbox ,it solves the second problem but the id issue still exists. I sorry I cant help you with the id issue I am not that used to Ant Designs.

Comment: ok but, have you observed the second point?

Comment: Yep, the second issue that you pointed out has been resolved, do check that out in the sandbox link that I have added in my original answer, I have updated the code in the sandbox. But still the 'id' issue persists.

Comment: Yes second issue is fixed and now working perfectly fine. It would have been great if 'id' issue was resolved. I'll try to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

you are always using the base newData element. so on each call of handleOnValuesChange you have no value set to disabled.

you need to update the newData or use some other temp variable.

also value is the first parameter for the onChange used by antd select.

```
let newData = [
  {
    id: 123,
    name: "Vijay",
    disabled: false,
  },
  {
    id: 345,
    name: "Sanket",
    disabled: false,
  },
  {
    id: 546,
    name: "Hitesh",
    disabled: false,
  },
  {
    id: 789,
    name: "Sameer",
    disabled: false,
  },
  {
    id: 421,
    name: "Akshay",
    disabled: false,
  }
];

const handleOnValuesChange = (val) => {
  console.log("VAL", val);
  newData = newData.map((data) => {
    console.log(data, val);
    if (data.id === val) {
      return {
        ...data,
        disabled: true
      };
    }
    return data;
  });
  console.log("NEW DATA", newData);
};
```

Comment: It worked for me. Excellent answer....

Answer (score 1):

I checked the sandbox code and found multiple issues with your code.

1. You have to change the `newData` value with update value otherwise it will old data for render.
2. You have to compare `if (data.id === val.value)` instead of `if (data.id === val)` in handleOnValuesChange function.
3. You have to return data only in else part.

You can check modified implementation on [Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/bordered-less-antd-4-17-0-alpha-7-forked-170es?file=/index.js:506-526)

It will be great if you use the state for `newData`

Comment: Only one quetion... how to show the disabled option in the drop-down list?

Comment: @Pranav you can add a disabled property of Select and get a `true and false` value from a function. This function will return the corresponding `true or false` value.

Comment: If you don't mind, can you show in the codesandbox?

Comment: Just update the sandbox but you have to use `newData` as react state only then it will update the DOM.

Comment: Actually my intention is that when one option selected from 'Data 1' gets disabled in 'Data 2'